# How to stop servlet processing from jsp page by button click

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created a JSP page which calls a servlet. And the total processing time of that servlet is minimum 5 minutes. Before full completion of that servlet's process, I want to stop the process and again want to call with different parameter.

I want to click a button from my JSP page which makes stop the total process of the servlet.

Comment: what is a problem? Your UI is freeze or you are asking to find a solution to be able to cancel servlet processing?

Comment: Vasif, Yes I want to able cancel servlet processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using java executor framework.

1. Create thread pool

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

2. Put your heavy task inside new thread and submit it to your executorService which will process and return Feature task for you. And save this feature in session

```
Future<String> startedTask = executorService.submit(() -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started!");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);//TODO: here goes your heavy task which tooks long to process
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "completed at " + System.currentTimeMillis();//here you can return your results if you need any
});
session.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_WORKING_TASK, startedTask);
```

As an additional, if you want to block your UI while servlet processes you can call below method after above lines (I don't think somebody wants to do it)

```
String result = startedTask.get();
```

3. When you call stop url via button you can find your task from session and cancel it

```
Object task = session.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_WORKING_TASK);
if (task == null)
   return "Task doesnt exists";
if (task instanceof Future)
   ((Future<String>) session.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_WORKING_TASK)).cancel(true);
```

This will cancel your task and even if you have blocked UI which was waiting servlet process will be unblocked